# How to insert a rectangle inside a text frame in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I have some text inside a textframe, and I'd like to be able to insert a rectangle amongst the flow of the text where the rectangle has a different background colour, different font etc.

How do I organise this? Should I have a text frame for the text above the rectangle, the rectangle, then another text frame below? I can simply drop the rectangle inside the textframe, but it doesn't affect the flow and feels dirty.

What's the correct InDesign approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - Select the rectangle, and then select "Jump Object" in the textflow window / panel.